# Exception on PySpark when write to Parquet

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with huge data at JSON format that is coverted to parquet using pySpark. In gral, all it is ok, but currently I am having issue on some transformation. But I could not debug or I don;t how overpass. I could transform a lot of data, but It seem issue but I could not detect or skip

````
    pc_attrs = json.map(js_loads).filter(shrink_).map(
        shrink_attrs).map(convert_time_pc_atts)

    s3aRdd = spark_session.createDataFrame(pc_attrs, procAttrsSchema)
    s3aRdd.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy("day","tenantId").parquet(
        s3_table_parquet)```


The exception:

```Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1595414885588_0004/container_1595414885588_0004_01_000228/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1595414885588_0004/container_1595414885588_0004_01_000228/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1595414885588_0004/container_1595414885588_0004_01_000228/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1595414885588_0004/container_1595414885588_0004_01_000228/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 2649 (char 2648)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec$$anonfun$1.apply(SortExec.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more```
````

Comment: Can you post full code ??

Comment: "JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string..." seems pretty unambiguous - your json is malformed.

Comment: unfortunately, I cant post the full, code. I can tell you seems to be load issue, when I convert less data is working. for instance if not partitytion by day just  "partitionBy("tenantid")